# Why does $\lim_{n\to 0}\frac{x^n-1}{n}$ = ln(x)$?

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponential-function

I was watching a 3blue1brown video about exponentials, and in explaining why $e$ is the base where the derivative/integral is the same as the original function, he uses the above fraction. Is there some way of showing it? I tried using l'hopital's rule, but that makes it $$\lim_{n\to 0}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{1}$$ which is 0.

Comment: Could you link to the time stamp in the video?

Comment: No, that's not what l'Hopital makes it. You've differentiated with respect to $x$ in the numerator and $n$ in the denominator.

Comment: Your L'hopital's calculation is incorrect

Comment: @Mark it happens at https://youtube.com/watch?v=m2MIpDrF7Es&t=280, although the OP may be referring to another video altogether.

Comment: By the way, if you really are watching the video that I liked in my previous comment, then you can't use l'Hopital, because you don't know how to differentiate the numerator yet; that's why we're interested in that limit in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you're watching the video that I think you're watching (https://youtu.be/m2MIpDrF7Es), and if I recall correctly, then there is nothing to prove here. That limit is some number that depends only on $x$, and he chooses to call that number $\ln x$.

Of course, you could then ask how to prove that $\ln$ defined this way is the inverse of the exponential map. That's a different question, and one that, in the light of the answers given here, should be asked more carefully and with greater attention to exactly what you're given and where you want to end up.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. If one uses the limit in question as a definition of logarithm function then one has to first deal with definition of symbol $x^{n} $ for all real $n$ without making use of logarithms. This is a non-trivial task and is mostly not given in introductory calculus texts. This approach has been outlined in my [blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-3.html).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Dealing with $x^n$ for real $n$ was done without logarithms at first in my math education. Define for rational $n$ using roots, then extend by continuity to real $n$.

Answer (score 0):

You should differentiate over $n$, not over $x$. So, we have $$\lim\limits_{n\to 0}\frac{x^n\ln x}{1}=\ln x.$$

Comment: Given that this happens in a derivation of how to differentiate $x^n$ with respect to $n$, your argument is circular.

Comment: In the context of differentiation of $f(n)=x^n$ at $n=0$, yes. If only the limit is needed to know - Hospital Rule is OK. Nevertheless, direct computation of the limit in question is a bit complicated, not for the first course in calculus.

Comment: @szw1710 No, it is **not** OK -- as Arthur pointed out, it is circular. You are trying to find the derivative of the function $f(t) = x^t$ at $0$ (this is, *by definition*, what that limit it). If you apply L'Hopital to compute it, *your first step is to differentiate $f$ (at all points in a neighborhood of $0$) in the numerator*.... But you cannot do that, since you do **not** know the derivative of $f$ -- that's what you want to find! If you do, you use the result you want (actually, something even stronger, since you only want $f'(0)$ but use $f'(t)$ for all $t$ around $0$) to compute it.

Comment: If we agree to allow power series and their differentiation, the proof that $(e^u)'_u=e^u$ is easy. Then everything could be done w/o circular argument by $x^n=e^{n\ln x}.$

Comment: @szw1710: if you really use power series then why go for the L'Hospital's Rule. The limit is obvious from the expansion $x^{n} =1+n\log x +o(n)$. The point is that you have access to a formula for $f'(x) $ which is also valid for point $x=a$ then you don't need to apply L'Hospital's Rule for the limit $\lim_{x\to a} \dfrac{f(x) - f(a)} {x-a} $ because you already know it to be $f'(a) $ and calculate it by putting $x=a$ in the formula for $f'(x) $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh How do you prove this expansion? I think that the derivative is a hidden actor of the whole (thread I think) spectacle.

Comment: @szw1710: by using your idea "if we use power series..." we get the desired expansion.

Answer (score 0):

use the fact that near $x= 0$ we have, $$e^x \sim 1+x + O(x^2)$$ then 
$$\frac{x^h-1}{h} = \frac{\exp(h\ln x)-1}{h} \sim \ln x+ O(h)\to \ln x$$

or by definition of derivative we have,
$$\lim_{n\to 0}\frac{x^n-1}{n} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\exp(h\ln x)-1}{h} =\frac{d}{da}(\exp(a\ln x))|_{a=0} =\ln x$$